# Web Scraper not returning the correct URL

Tags: c#, .net, web, web-scraping, console-application

So I'm trying to develop a web scraper console app in c#. I'm having trouble retrieving the post links from this website. [Hacker News](https://news.ycombinator.com/)

I can retrieve everything else but the link. When I try getting the link it returns me with the vote button link rather than the post link, tho I believe I'm selecting the right tags.

My code:

```
var postsHTML = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.Descendants("table")
    .Where(node => node.GetAttributeValue("class", "")
    .Equals("itemlist")).ToList();

var postList = postsHTML[0].Descendants("tr")
    .Where(node => node.GetAttributeValue("class", "")
    .Equals("athing")).ToList();
```

And then in my foreach loop to access the elements in the array and to retrieve the link I input this:

```
foreach (var post in postList)
{

    Console.WriteLine("Title: " + post.Descendants("a")
        .Where(node => node.GetAttributeValue("class", "")
        .Equals("storylink")).FirstOrDefault().InnerText);


    Console.WriteLine("URI: " + post.Descendants("a").FirstOrDefault()
        .GetAttributeValue("href", ""));

    Console.WriteLine();

}
```

That's returning the title correctly but my URI seems to be coming as

**Title:** Jules Verne’s Most Famous Books Were Part of a 54-Volume Masterpiece

**URI:** vote?id=22292003&how=up&goto=news

and the link that I'd expect to return is the post link:

**URI:** http://www.openculture.com/2020/02/jules-vernes-voyages-extraordinaires.html

Answer (score 1):

You are selecting the wrong tag the second time. You should reuse the same selector because the Title and Url are in the same tag.

```
var storyLink = post.Descendants("a")
    .Where(node => node.GetAttributeValue("class", "")
    .Equals("storylink")).FirstOrDefault();

Console.WriteLine("Title: " + storyLink.InnerText);


Console.WriteLine("URI: " + storyLink.GetAttributeValue("href", ""));
```